# how to read a line from file with different line size in c++?

Tags: c++, file, readfile

I am trying to read from file like this

```
2                   #number of process

1                   #process name
0 1000              #start and finsh time of process
1 400               #number of memmory #memmory size

2                   #process name
0 2000              #start and finsh time of process
2 200 400           #number of memmory #memmory size
```

number of process and number of memory can be different
my main problem is how to read from file with different number of memeory?

Comment: Your `number of processes` is a kind of header in your file. You can easily read this value and starting a loop. In each loop you can read values line by line from stream and with the help of an inner loop for `number of memory` you will be able to read your file.

Comment: You know how many numbers are on each line, it's the first number.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input file is well-formed and doesn't contain any errors, you can read the numbers as is, and then use loops to read the variable-amount records or values.

Perhaps something like this:

```
int process_count;
file >> process_count;

for (unsigned p = 0; p < process_count; ++p)
{
    int process_name, start_time, finish_time, memory_count;
    std::vector<int> memory;

    file >> process_name >> start_time >> finish_time >> memory_count;

    for (unsigned m = 0; m < memory_count; ++m)
    {
        int memory_size;
        file >> memory_size;
        memory.push_back(memory_size);
    }

    // Here all data for the "process" have been read from the file, use it...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd define a type to keep the information for one process and then add streaming operators for that type. The collected processes would be perfect to store in a `std::vector`.

Example:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

// define a type for a process entry
struct process {
    long name;
    std::time_t start;
    std::time_t end;
    // a vector for all your memory sizes:
    std::vector<std::size_t> mem_sizes;
};

// operator for reading one process from a stream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, process& p) {
    if(unsigned number_of_memory;
       is >> p.name >> p.start >> p.end >> number_of_memory)
    {
        p.mem_sizes.clear(); // remove any old memory sizes

        for(std::size_t tmp; number_of_memory && is >> tmp; --number_of_memory) {
            p.mem_sizes.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }
    return is;
}

// operator for writing one process to a stream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const process& p) {
    if(os << p.name << '\n'
          << p.start << ' ' << p.end << '\n'
          << p.mem_sizes.size())
    {
        for(std::size_t mem_size : p.mem_sizes) 
            os << ' ' << mem_size;
    }
    return os << '\n';
}

int main() {
    // example file
    std::istringstream file(
        "2\n"         // #number of process
        "\n"          //
        "1\n"         // #process name
        "0 1000\n"    // #start and finsh time of process
        "1 400\n"     // #number of memmory #memmory size
        "\n"          //
        "2\n"         // #process name
        "0 2000\n"    // #start and finsh time of process
        "2 200 400\n" // #number of memmory #memmory size
    );

    // collected processes
    std::vector<process> processes;

    // std::ifstream file("filename");
    if(file) {
        // read processes
        if(int process_count; file >> process_count) {
            for(process tmp; process_count && file >> tmp; --process_count) {
                processes.push_back(tmp);
            }
        }
    }

    // print the collected processes:
    std::cout << processes.size() << '\n';
    for(const process& p : processes) {
        std::cout << '\n' << p;
    }
}
```